# Error of typemap in Swig interface

Tags: python, c++, swig

I get the error:

> Warning 453: Can't apply `(int DIM1,int DIM2,double** INPLACE_ARRAY1)`. No typemaps are defined.

Here, the prototype of my C function is the following:

```
void function(const int size1, double* Tab1,
              const int size2, double* Tab2,
              const int size3, double* Tab3,
              const double alpha)
```

Using `numpy.i` I write the Swig interface `function.i` as follows:

```
%module function

%{
   #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
   #include "function.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%apply (int DIM1, double* INPLACE_ARRAY1) {
          (const int size1, double* Tab1),
          (const int size2, double* Tab2),
          (const int size3, double* Tab3)};

%apply (int DIM1, int DIM2, double** INPLACE_ARRAY1) {
          (const int size1, const int size2, double** Tab1)};

%include "function.h"
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation for [numpy.i](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html), you will see that there is no such thing as a typemap matching `(int DIM1, int DIM2, double** INPLACE_ARRAY1)`. That is what the warning means (can't apply the typemap because no such is defined).

Also, it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. `(const int size1, const int size2, double** Tab1)` doesn't occur as arguments in your function, so such a typemap would not match your function anyway.

It seems that simply removing the lines

```
%apply (int DIM1, int DIM2, double** INPLACE_ARRAY1) {
      (const int size1, const int size2, double** Tab1)};
```

should entirely resolve your problem.